# How to add a module to Python's list of globally importable libraries

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to work in an environment where I cannot install packages normally using Pip. As such, I need to bundle all my program's dependencies alongside the full program. This works great for simpler dependencies, but for ones that have their own dependencies, imports fail due to their dependencies not being globally available (since neither of them can be imported using absolute imports).

Currently, my modules are as follows:

```
main.py (uses my_module)
my_module/ (depends on foo)
    somefile.py
    anotherfile.py
foo/ (depends on bar)
    # Contents of third-party module
bar/
    # Contents of other third-party module
```

Is there a way that I can alias a module that I have imported relatively, so that whenever some other module tries to import it, it will be referred to the place where I have directed it? I'd much rather do that than have to risk modifying thousands of lines of unfamiliar code to make all the import statements relative.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom pip package as explained here:

[Use custom Python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019187/use-custom-python-package)

Comment: This doesn't really help since the environment I'm in has no support for Pip.

Comment: @HDSQ.mid you dont need pip to install pip packages. you can just run "setup.py" inside the package itself